# Nodejs error stack trace displays incorrectly

Tags: node.js

Whenever I get an error in nodejs the error displays improperly, looks like:

```
Error: not opened
    at WebSocket.send (C:\Users\strik\node_modules\[4mws[24m\lib\WebSocket.js:219:16)
    at getClanData (C:\Users\strik\Desktop\Programs\JavaScriptCoding\KBot3\index.js:167:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\strik\Desktop\Programs\JavaScriptCoding\KBot3\index.js:308:1)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
```

Nodejs version:

```
node -v
12.14.1

npm -v
6.13.4
```

As far as I can tell all nodejs errors output like this

Comment: These look like ANSI control sequences intended to display things in color in your console.  I'm not sure why you are getting them.

Comment: FYI, you can see in the node.js `console.log()` code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L266) how that code looks at several factors including whether `stream.isTTY` is true to determine whether to use colors.  Are you using a command shell that does not support ANSI escape sequences?

Comment: Nope, im using an up to date version of windows 10 command prompt. I had been working fine until i uninstalled then re-installed nodejs. I never had the problem previously